# Rails 3.2 CRUD : .where with 'or' conditional

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

With ruby on rails, I want to do something like:

```
 @tasks = Task.where(:def => true || :house_id => current_user.house_id)
```

What is the most efficient/clean way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Task.where("def = ? or house_id = ?", true, current_user.house_id)
```

The general case is:

```
Model.where("column = ? or other_column = ?", value, other_value)
```

You can also leverage Arel:

```
t = Task.arel_table

@tasks = Task.where(
  t[:def].eq(true).
  or(t[:house_id].eq(current_user.house_id))
)
```